# No puedo enviar facturas al webservice SII de AEAT

Tags: php, aeat-sii

No he cambiado nada en mi código fuente que hace unos días funcionaba perfectamente, pero hoy al intentar enviar facturas da el siguiente error:

```
2022/11/17 11:03:16 [error] [php] SoapClient::SoapClient(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed (/var/www/html/abac56/abac/protected/modules/sii/components/SiiComponent.php:165)
```

He mirado en la web oficial:
https://sede.agenciatributaria.gob.es/Sede/procedimientoini/G417.shtml

En el apartado de definición de servicios:
https://sede.agenciatributaria.gob.es/Sede/impuestos-tasas/iva/iva-libros-registro-iva-traves-aeat/wsdl-servicios-web.html

Y he actualizado las rutas a las definiciones usando estas:
https://sede.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/Sede/Procedimiento_ayuda/G417/FicherosSuministros/V_1_1/WSDL/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl
https://sede.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/Sede/Procedimiento_ayuda/G417/FicherosSuministros/V_1_1/WSDL/SuministroFactRecibidas.wsdl

Y ahora al intentar enviar una factura ya no sale el error de antes, sino que sale otro:

```
2022/11/17 12:29:37 [error] [php] SoapClient::SoapClient(https://sede.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/Sede/Procedimiento_ayuda/G417/FicherosSuministros/V_1_1/WSDL/SuministroInformacion.xsd): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Es como si la definición estuviera mal hecha y no consigue importar unos archivos.

Al buscar en Google me he encontrado con esto:

[Bug #73043 WSDL: import schema if WSDL uri does NOT end with a slash](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73043)

Y entiendo que en algunos casos depende cómo está hecha la definición puede que no encuentre algún archivo, y recomienda como solución alternativa, bajárselo todo a local.

He intentado también bajar todos los archivos a local, pero al probarlo me da otros errores raros de los campos `PeriodoImpositivo` y `PeriodoLiquidacion`, primero se queja de uno, y si lo pongo, se queja del otro, hay como una inconsistencia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer hay algo que no encaja en la definición de los servicios que se encuentran en esta página:

https://sede.agenciatributaria.gob.es/Sede/impuestos-tasas/iva/iva-libros-registro-iva-traves-aeat/wsdl-servicios-web.html

Tras realizar varias pruebas y revisar la web de la AEAT, se ha consultado el documento PDF de manual técnico del SII:
https://sede.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/Sede/Procedimiento_ayuda/G417/FicherosSuministros/V_1_1/SII_Descripcion_ServicioWeb_v1.1.pdf

En este se pueden ver las URLs de los servicios:
[image: Definición servicios SII AEAT PDF]

Al usar las URLs que aparecen en el PDF, con estas sí que funciona:

https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii_1_1_bis/fact/ws/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl
https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii_1_1_bis/fact/ws/SuministroFactRecibidas.wsdl

Por lo tanto entiendo que se trata de un error por parte de AEAT ya que los enlaces de definición que muestran en la web no sirven o están desactualizados.

Comment: ¿Esto ha resuelto tu problema?

Comment: @A.Cedano sí con eso se me ha resuelto el problema, justamente por eso lo comparto con la comunidad

Comment: Perfecto, entonces pasado el tiempo prudente la puedes marcar como respuesta aceptada y podrá servir a futuros usuarios con un problema parecido. Saludos.